# Postgres - determine if identifier should be quote

Tags: postgresql

I'm looking to build a postgres query dynamically. This will include an identifier name. To make the output as readable as possible, I am planning to quote only when necessary, and assume that the user passes the exact identifier name.

Some example inputs, and ideal outputs:

- table name input: `hello`, output: `select * from hello`
- table name input: `Hello`, output: `select * from "Hello"` (caps)
- table name input: `select`, output: `select * from "select"` (keyword)

So, I'm looking for a list of keywords that will need to be quoted, even if the passed input is all lowercase. Is there a meta table in postgres that can provide this, or should I hard-code it based on [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html)? A queryable meta table seems better to me, in case more keywords are added (even if it's unlikely to happen in a breaking way).

Comment: Just double quote everything. That is what ORM's(at least the ones I have used) do. It is also what is done when you using parameter passing in client libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a list of reserved keywords with

```
SELECT word
FROM pg_get_keywords()
WHERE catdesc = 'reserved';
```

But I recommend a different approach. Most client APIs offer a way to safely quote identifiers, like libpq's [`PQescapeIdentifier`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-exec.html#LIBPQ-PQESCAPEIDENTIFIER) or the JDBC driver's [`org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.html.escapeIdentifier()`](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/jdbc/PgConnection.html#escapeIdentifier-java.lang.String-). You should use these functions rather than re-inventing the wheel and risking security bugs if you did it wrong.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I plan to use an existing escape utility. But for the sake of readability, I would like to _not_ escape non-keyword, all-lowercase identifiers - my assumption is that a regex like `/^[a-z][a-z_\d]*$/` + reserved-keyword check is good enough. node-postgres, the client I am using, has an escapeIdentifier function, but it always adds quotes.

Comment: That's what these functions do anyway - they only add quotes if necessary.